# How to obtain negative and positive voltage (±16V) for LM324N

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative-voltage

I'm working with the LM324N op-amp. My project requires dual supply, ±16V. How can I produce negative and positive supply from a single supply source?

[Some project](http://gureckislab.org/blog/?p=3027) have been using ICL7760 to obtain -5V. For my project, what IC type can I used to produce -16V?

Comment: What input voltages do you have?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Tell us about the power sources you already have available and provide a schematic of your op amp circuit.

Comment: +/- 16V is decidedly non-standard. Can you get away with +/- 15 volts, which is? Equally important, exactly how much current do you require?

Comment: My input voltages is not fix yet. Maybe less than 20V.

Comment: Right now, temporarily,  I'm using programmable power supply which can provide positive and negative voltage. However it is bulky since my final project should be in a portable shape. That's why I want to replace the power supply with something simple and less weight.

Comment: Yes +/- 15V is acceptable. As i seen the current required is less than 100mA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to get a 32v power supply then create a virtual ground halfway between VDD and GND. This can be done with a simple resistor divider, or by using an op amp, possibly buffered with mosfets.

Another option is to purchase a self contained power supply that provides positive and negative output. I didn't see any in my brief search that provide +/- 16, but I found many that provide +/- 24v, for example: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cui-inc/PEM1-S5-D24-S/102-3031-5-ND/4006999

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm interested in your 2nd option. However the PEM1-S5-D24-S is not available at the nearest shop. Thus I need to buy online and it will take time for delivery process. So, i would like to try the 1st option. Actually, I am newbie in electric and electronic works. I would be happy and if you can provide me with schematic diagram so it will be easier to understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What type of IC?

Most buck regulator ICs can be used to create negative rails. connect the buck converter output to ground and buck converter ground to your negative rail.

connect input to regulator input and ground (regulator output)

you need to use a buck regulator that can withstand the difference between the input and output voltage (sum of the magnitudes of the two voltages)

https://training.ti.com/inverting-made-simple